# Выбрать структуру(ы) для реализации кэша файловой системы

Tags: java, spring, архитектура, коллекции, java-hashmap

Нужно реализовать аналог дропбокса/тимвивера.

Есть сервер, он наблюдает за некоторой директорией. Когда в ней происходят изменения, он оповещает (через amqp, реализации RabbitMq) клиентов.
Сервер реализован. Кэш тоже, но хочется все оптимизировать.

На данный момент существующий кэш  построен на основе

```
static Map<String, String> fileCash = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

Т.к. клиенту требуется только список файлов, то он содержит только абсолютный путь (ключ) и в значении тип файла - дирекория ("dir") или файл (файл).

Т.к. файлы хранятся на одном уровне в структуре , то удалении реализовано не рационально - при удалении директории

1. мы получаем в в нашем хэш-тейбл все ключи
2. вызываем метод У String.contains, проверяеме ВО ВСЕХ ключах(которые являются абсолютными путями к файлу) наличие части строки, которая является частью директории.
3. Если в в названии файла есть название директории, то значит удаленная директория, его содержала и мы удаляем файл.

ГЛавный минус в том, что мы получаем все ключи из нашего **Map**.

Вижу два варианта оптимизации:

1. Сделать список или массив файлов, в котором каждое значение или содержит абсолютный путь или, если это директория, содержит ссылку на другой массив.
2. Использовать **JPA**, но реализация бд должна быть в оперативной памяти, типа h2.

Подскажите, какие на ваш взгляд варианты оптимизации данной системы вы видите, какие структуры данных лучше использовать.
Может нужно реализовать **Map**, который содержит **Map**? В случае директории

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import prcjt.fileswork.DirectoryScanner;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.*;

@Component
public class FileListCash {

    static Map<String, String> fileCash = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    @Autowired
    private DirectoryScanner dirScanner;

    /**
     * adding new Files and dir to Cash
     *
     * @param listFile list of adding files and dir's
     */
    public void addDir(List<File> listFile) {
        for (File file : listFile) {
            if (file.isDirectory())
                fileCash.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), "dir");
            else
                fileCash.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), "file");
        }

    }
    //ПЕРЕДЕЛАТЬ СТРОКИ НА КОНСТАНТЫ?

    /**
     * @param change type of Change ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY
     * @param path   absolute path of file
     */
    public void eventHandle(String change, String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        switch (change) {
            case "ENTRY_CREATE":
                //если новый объект директория, тогда добавляем в кэш СПИСОК ЕЕ СОДЕРЖИМОГО(dir scznner отдаст список, который обрабатывается в методе addDir)
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    fileCash.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), "dir");
                    ///!!! занести в метод добавления
                    addDir(dirScanner.scanPath(path));
                } else
                    fileCash.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), "file");

                break;
            case "ENTRY_DELETE":
                //если это диеректория
                if (fileCash.get(file.getAbsolutePath()).equals("dir")) {
                    deleteDir(file);

                } else
                    fileCash.remove(file.getAbsolutePath());
                break;
            case "ENTRY_MODIFY":
                break;
        }
        return;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCash() {
        return fileCash;
    }

    public void addFile(File file) {
        fileCash.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), "file");
    }

    /**
     * delete recursion inner files and dir
     *
     * @param dir
     */
    public void deleteDir(File dir) {
        //Если во всем множестве есть совпадение с путем, значит, это дочерний узел, удаляем его
        // список файлов, которые нужно удалить
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String path : fileCash.keySet()) {
            if (path.contains(dir.getAbsolutePath())) {
                paths.add(path);
            }
        }
        for (String path: paths){
            fileCash.remove(path);
        }
    }
}
ЦЕЛЬ ВСЕГО ЭТОГО:
чтобы при удалении каталога, удалялись файлы в нем и подкаталоги.
```

Comment: почему решили использовать Hashtable? у вас много потоков могут вызвать методы которые меняют fileCash? Cash - это наличные деньги! :) правильно будет Cache.

Comment: можете описать ответственность **FileListCash**? для чего надо кешировать список файлов?

Comment: Есть клиент, которому нужно отправлять актуальное состояние файловой системы. Чтобы каждый раз не сканировать файловую систему на изменения при запросе он и нужен, в данный момент при удалении файлов, ему не надо снова опрашивать ОС, кэш сам удалят их из своей структуры